# How to post data when clicking custom ui component button?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, adminform, ui-form

I am using ui-component form edit and would like to add custom button "customButton" with all post data. However, it doesn't post any data except form key.

My code

```
 $data = [
            'label' => __('Print Address'),
            'class' => 'save',
            'data_attribute' => [
                'url' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl('*/*/printAddress', ['id' => $this->getRequest->getParam('id')]);
            ],
            'sort_order' => 80,
        ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check CMS module as an example. You need to pass following params for submit form.

> vendor/magento/module-cms/Block/Adminhtml/Page/Edit/SaveButton.php

```
'data_attribute' => [
    'mage-init' => [
        'buttonAdapter' => [
            'actions' => [
                [
                    'targetName' => 'cms_page_form.cms_page_form',
                    'actionName' => 'save',
                    'params' => [
                        false
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
],
```

Comment: But how it knows which url to call?